# C# Parse xml into arrays

Tags: c#, .net

I have 400+ records of data in this format inside :

```
<rs:data>
   <z:row ows_ID='360' ows_LinkTitle='GEI Survey data to Sharepoint' ows_Project_x0020_Priority='0' ows_AssignedTo='615;#Jeremy, Ron' ows_Status='In Progress' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_DueDate='2012-04-27 00:00:00' ows_PercentComplete='0.700000000000000' ows_Modified='2012-04-30 10:44:15' ows_Alignment='TSS Delivery Mgmt' ows_SME='44;#Lewis, Clark' />

   <z:row ows_ID='378' ows_LinkTitle='Create back end and environment to support User demographic reporting' ows_Project_x0020_Priority='0' ows_AssignedTo='615;#Sam, Johns' ows_Status='In Progress' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_DueDate='2012-05-11 00:00:00' ows_PercentComplete='0.800000000000000' ows_Modified='2012-05-09 13:50:17' ows_Alignment='Team Internal' ows_SME='7;#CORP\sscer;#9;#CORP\vreer' />

   <z:row ows_ID='249' ows_LinkTitle='Training Material to Muti Media' ows_AssignedTo='620;#Jenkins, Kristen' ows_Status='Not Started' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_DueDate='2012-08-10 00:00:00' ows_PercentComplete='0' ows_Modified='2012-05-16 11:20:29' ows_Alignment='Diver Support' ows_SME='1;#CORP\vsswer;#7;#CORP\adder' />

</rs:data>
```

how do I create indivisual array to store the values of ows_ID, ows_LinkTitle annd so on?

> foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in activeItemData)
>
> ```
>         {
>             if (node.Name == "rs:data")
>             {
>                 for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
>                 {
>                     if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "z:row")
>                     {
>                         string [] resultTitle;
>      resultTitle = (node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_Title"].Value).ToArray();
>                         Console.ReadLine(); 
>                     } 
>                 } 
>           } 
>       }
> ```

Its throwing error Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'string[]' at resultTitle. How do I correct it? Thanks.

I did

```
char[] resultTitle;
resultTitle = (node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes ["ows_Title"].Value).ToArray();
string s = new string(resultTitle);
Console.ReadLine();
```

how do I do it for all the values of ["ows_Title"]. ? Thanks.

Comment: We have no idea what `rs` or `z` mean (other than being some xml namespaces). What is your real xml and what exactly do want to get out of it?

Comment: L.B- The real xml is the data returned from a web reference to a SharePoint list. I m thinking of getting arrays of all the values of the attributes like [ows_ID], [ows_Title] etc in indivisual arrays so that I can pass them as parameters to insert those values into my SQL table. If you want to take a look at what it looks like- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739535/insert-xml-attribute-values-in-a-sql-table

Comment: No thanks I can not say that i am much interested in how it looks after seeing your problem was `char[]` :)

Comment: @L.B. actually the problem is `.ToArray()`

Comment: @ConradFrix My comment was referring the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
char[] resultTitle;
resultTitle = (node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes ["ows_Title"].Value).ToArray(); 
string s = new string(resultTitle);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Takes a string value turns into a character array. `).ToArray()` and then immediately converts the character array back into a string.

This is the same thing without the extra memory allocation

```
string s = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes ["ows_Title"].Value;
```

---

If I were you however I would just use linq to xml. I'd also want to end up with a `List<string>`

```
XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
List<string> list = (from row in xdoc.Descendants(z + "row")
                     select (string)row.Attribute("ows_LinkTitle")
                    ).ToList();
```

Complete sample

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xstring = @"<xml xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
                         xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
                            <rs:data>
                                <z:row ows_ID='360' ows_LinkTitle='GEI Survey data to Sharepoint' ows_Project_x0020_Priority='0' ows_AssignedTo='615;#Jeremy, Ron' ows_Status='In Progress' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_DueDate='2012-04-27 00:00:00' ows_PercentComplete='0.700000000000000' ows_Modified='2012-04-30 10:44:15' ows_Alignment='TSS Delivery Mgmt' ows_SME='44;#Lewis, Clark' />
                               <z:row ows_ID='378' ows_LinkTitle='Create back end and environment to support User demographic reporting' ows_Project_x0020_Priority='0' ows_AssignedTo='615;#Sam, Johns' ows_Status='In Progress' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_DueDate='2012-05-11 00:00:00' ows_PercentComplete='0.800000000000000' ows_Modified='2012-05-09 13:50:17' ows_Alignment='Team Internal' ows_SME='7;#CORP\sscer;#9;#CORP\vreer' />
                               <z:row ows_ID='249' ows_LinkTitle='Training Material to Muti Media' ows_AssignedTo='620;#Jenkins, Kristen' ows_Status='Not Started' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_DueDate='2012-08-10 00:00:00' ows_PercentComplete='0' ows_Modified='2012-05-16 11:20:29' ows_Alignment='Diver Support' ows_SME='1;#CORP\vsswer;#7;#CORP\adder' />
                          </rs:data> 
                          </xml>";



        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xstring); // there are other ways to construct your xdoc
        XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
        List<string> list = (from row in xdoc.Descendants(z + "row")
                            select  (string)row.Attribute("ows_LinkTitle")
                            ).ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
            Console.WriteLine(item);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Conrad Frix for your help. LINQ to XML is really nice thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just use

```
char[] resultTitle;
```

instead of

```
string [] resultTitle;
```